# Generate Wsdl/Client Stubs For Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, wsimport

I have been doing some reading up on web services programming with Java, Eclipse, etc. and I found one particular example where the person created the web service and client by doing the following:

1. define the web service java class (interface + impl)
2. *deploy* the web service using *Endpoint.publish*
3. grab the *wsdl* from the url of the web service (eg, localhost://greeting?wsdl)
4. use *wsimport* to generate stubs
5. create a client class using generated stubs

Is there another way to generate the *wsdl* without having to publish the web service and download it? Perhaps a maven plugin to auto-generate wsdl and client stubs?

**Update**: Rather than creating a new question I am just going to piggyback on this one.

I have created my web service by defining an interface:

```
@WebService
public interface HelloWorldWs {
    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(String name);
}
```

and an impl class:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.me.helloworldws.HelloWorldWs")
public class HelloWorldWsImpl implements HelloWorldWs {
    @Override
    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello World Ws, " + name;
    }
}
```

When I run *wsgen* I get the following error:

```
The @javax.jws.WebMethod annotation cannot be used in with @javax.jws.WebService.endpointInterface element.
```

Eclipse seems to be okay with it.

Any idea why?

Note, I originally did not have the annotation but when I tried to call my webservice I got the following error:

```
com.me.helloworldws.HelloWorldWsImpl is not an interface
```

Comment: I am learning Web Services in java and i am looking for the above example `where the person created the web .. bla bla`. Can you send me link of that example, it would be very helpful for me to understand the Web Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JSR 224](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224) says in 3.1 section:

> An SEI is a Java interface that meets all of the following criteria:
>
> - Any of its methods MAY carry a `javax.jws.WebMethod` annotation (see 7.11.2).
> - `javax.jws.WebMethod` if used, MUST NOT have the `exclude` element set to `true`.

If the implementation class include the `javax.jws.WebMethod`, then you cant put `@WebMethod(exclude=true)` and that in not possible, according to specification.

Depends of custom version of Eclipse, shows a warning for this. e.g. Rational Application Developer for Websphere shows:

```
JSR-181, 3.1: WebMethod cannot be used with the endpointInterface 
              property of WebService
```

Comment: Already done that! :) I even created elaborate batch files to do the wsgen/wsimport stuff I need. I was just hoping there was something like a maven plug-in to do all that for me.

Comment: Curious.. I have created an interface for my webservice and then an impl class and annotated the impl class with @WebService(endpointInterface = "com.cookmv.helloworldws.HelloWorldWs"). Wsgen complains about using enpointInterface. Any idea why?

Comment: The JAX-WS runtime use o not use the annotations, like Axis2 in Websphere no take the name.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more please? If it doesn't use the annotations what does it use?

Answer (score 0):

While programming/building a project (with some advanced IDE) normally you should be able to find it between auto-generated stuff - the IDE should generate it. Just check carefully.

Comment: If you don't find it (which is unlikely) try create a test web service client, IDE normally let you did it. It should be there (between test client files)